# compare two string value

Tags: c#, string, compare

I'd like to compare two string values​​, like this:

```
if (lblCapacity.Text <= lblSizeFile.Text)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The text properties being numeric values? You could use `Int32.Parse`

Comment: What does `<=` mean in this context?

Comment: @Oded : i suppose less or equal relative to lexicographic sort

Comment: @DonCallisto - I don't like to suppose, which is why I have asked the OP.

Comment: Agreed, this is actually a fine question *if the OP defined the meaning of "less than"*. Without that, we could be talking about alphabetic, length, caps vs lower case, or something else. Too bad the OP never came back to clarify.

Answer (score 41):

I'm assuming that you are comparing strings in [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), in which case you can use the Static method String.Compare.

For example, you have two strings str1 and str2, and you want to see if str1 comes before str2 in an alphabet. Your code would look like this :

```
string str1 = "A string";
string str2 = "Some other string";
if(String.Compare(str1,str2) < 0)
{
   // str1 is less than str2
   Console.WriteLine("Yes");
}
else if(String.Compare(str1,str2) == 0)
{
   // str1 equals str2
   Console.WriteLine("Equals");
}
else
{
   // str11 is greater than str2, and String.Compare returned a value greater than 0
   Console.WriteLine("No");
}
```

This above code would return yes. There are many overloaded versions of String.Compare, including some where you can ignore case, or use format strings. Check out [String.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.compare(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Of course I forgot to mention that the Control.Text property returns a string, which is why String.Compare is what I used.

Comment: Just a word of warning for the reader unfamiliar with lexicographical order, this means that "9" will be bigger than "13246", but "13" is smaller than "13246".

Answer (score 6):

```
int capacity;
int fileSize;

if (!int.TryParse(lblCapacity.Text, out capacity) //handle parsing problem;
if (!int.TryParse(lblSizeFile.Text, out fileSize) //handle parsing problem;

if (capacity <= fileSize) //... do something.
```

Comment: +1, this is what I will require if someone write code for my shop

Answer (score 2):

If you have integers in textbox then,

```
int capacity;
int fileSize;

if(Int32.TryParse(lblCapacity.Text,out capacity) && 
   Int32.TryParse(lblSizeFile.Text,out fileSize))
{
    if(capacity<=fileSize)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the labels contain numbers. Then you could try [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx):

```
if (int.Parse(lblCapacity.Text) <= int.Parse(lblSizeFile.Text))
```

Of course you might want to add some error checking (look at [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) and maybe store the parsed int values in some variables, but this is the basic concept.

Answer (score 1):

Compare is what you need.

```
int c = string.Compare(a , b);
```

Comment: When you want  `"11" < "2" == true`.

Comment: The question doesn't indicate its a numeric value

Answer (score 0):

Use `Int32.Parse`, `Int32.TryParse` or other equivalent. You can then numerically compare these values.